# can I use two facebook app ids for one website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token, facebook-app-requests

I have two websites A.com and B.fm which have two independent Facebook app ids, but I want to merge B into A and make my business approachable by more users (B will have urls like A.com/B/all_b's_original_urls) and B is served in different service (on different server) from A's server, can I make two Facebook ids works on A.com if change B.fm to A.com/B/all_b's_original_urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can use two facebook app ids for one website. Actually [B.fm](https://www.blackfriday.fm) works as [an independent service](https://www.dealsplus.com/blackfriday/) in A.com, so it doesn't influence [A.com](https://www.dealsplus.com/) at all.